# Create Mock Service API using Apiary

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I'm attempting to create mock api services for testing purposes. We are already using Apiary on another team so I'm starting there.

So far, I've noticed that if I want to have two separate calls requires mocking out of both requests. For example to get the notes with ids 1 and 2 requires explicitly writing out responses like:

/notes/1
/notes/2

Is there a way to avoid this? Admittedly I'm still ramping up on creating blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [private-e9e59-pingdomcheck.apiary-mock.com/v1/gists/1](https://private-e9e59-pingdomcheck.apiary-mock.com/v1/gists/1). The number `1` is `{id}` here. You of course get only the general defined response (like if I used id 42).

There are more things being done right now in [MSON](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson). Once it's released, different replies for different parameters in request will be possible.