# How to model different requests to same resource in api-blueprint/apiary

Tags: rest, apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I'm writing some API definitions with apiary/api blueprint.

Is there a way that, for the same resource, I can use the mock endpoint to behave differently depending on input (or failing that, some kind of work around)?

For example, say I have an endpoint /login, to which you are supposed to post a username and password.

If I set up a request and response in the API that successfully logs me in, and subsequent requests and response that are error scenarios, only the first one gets triggered in the mock.

So for example, if I don't send in a username and password, I still get the logged in successfully response.

Is there any way to get the mock to do more validation or how do you work around this?

Thanks

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682002/create-mock-service-api-using-apiary/28901799#28901799

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and thoroughly described in the documentation. See http://support.apiary.io/knowledgebase/articles/117119-handling-multiple-actions-on-a-single-resource

Comment: Thanks. The link you provided does not appear to deal with parameters, only different Content Types? There is a link on that page to a page about different parameters, but that doesn't deal with question of posting different parameters as the body to a resource, as in my question? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not implemented yet, but is being worked on. Have a look at [MSON](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson), please.